# Android Studio tool to find out why Recycler View is lagging?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've got a RecyclerView that's lagging quite a bit while scrolling. Each item can have different content types (videos, images, etc.), so it's difficult to pinpoint which of these may be causing the lag.

What tools in Android Studio should I be using to determine the cause of the lag?

Comment: You could enable [strict mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode) to check if you are doing anything on the UI thread like disk or network operations that would slow it down.

Comment: Use the profiler: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile I haven't used those Benchmark ones, they might be useful, but the "traditional" way is the CPU profiler: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler You can see how long it spends doing particular calls, or things like I/O, and work out where the bottleneck is. There's a good official video series here, there's a bunch to learn but it can be real useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktknfQykhXU